# How to rename sheets

Tags: vba, excel

How do I rename a sheet by referencing its position? That is, if I want to rename the second sheet, without using a code such as:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "New Name"
```

As this creates problems when my code adds sheets, and if in the past a sheet was deleted from the workbook it won't necessarily correspond to the next number in line.

Example: if I delete Sheet1 and then create a new one it will be Sheet2, but for the sake of not having to change the macro every time I use it I just want to reference to the position of the tab. And say the firstSheet, rename to "New Name".

Is that possible or is there a workaround?

Comment: `sheets(2).name = "New Name"`.  Just put the position number in.

Answer (score 1):

The `Sheets` collection is indexed by an index (position) or name, both of which are unique. For a new workbook, these should result the same:

```
MsgBox Sheets("Sheet1").Name
MsgBox Sheets(1).Name
```

So, for your question:

> How do I rename a sheet by referencing it's position?

Use the *index* of the sheet.

```
Sheets(_index_).Name = "New Name"
```